# Laravel Eloquent Relationship: HasRelationships.php FatalErrorExexeption

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade, eloquent

I have an `asset_category` table(columns '`asset_category_id`', '`category`') and an `asset` table(columns '`asset_id`', '`asset_category_id`') and want display the (columns `'asset_id'`, `'asset_category_id.category,'`) from the `asset` table instead of just the `'asset_id'` n `'asset_category_id'` columns.

**Asset_CatoriesController**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Asset_category;

class Asset_CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    public function asset_category(){
        $asset_categories = Asset_category::all();
        return view('category', ['asset_categories' => $asset_categories]);
    }

    public function add(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'asset_category_id' => '',
            'category' => 'required'
        ]);
        $asset_categories =  new Asset_category;
        $asset_categories ->asset_category_id = $request->input('asset_category_id');
        $asset_categories ->category = $request->input('category');
        $asset_categories ->save();
        return redirect('/category') ->with('info', 'New Category Saved Successfully!');
    }

    public function update($id){
        $asset_categories = Asset_category::find($id);
        return view('update', ['asset_categories' => $asset_categories]);

    }

    public function edit(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'asset_category_id' => '',
            'category' => 'required'
        ]);
        $data = array(
            'category' => $request ->input('category')
        );
        Asset_category::where('asset_category_id', $id)->update($data);
        return redirect('/category') ->with('info', 'Category Updated Successfully!');
    }

    public function delete($id){
        Asset_category::where('asset_category_id', $id)
            ->delete();
        return redirect('/category') ->with('info', 'Category Deleted Successfully!');
    }
}
```

**AssetController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Asset;
use App\Asset_category;
use App\Manufacturer;
use App\Department;



use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AssetController extends Controller
{
    public function asset(){
        $assets = Asset::all();
       // return view::make('viewAsset')->with('assets', $assets);
        return view('viewAsset', ['assets' => $assets]);
    }

    public function manufacturer(){
        $manufacturers = Manufacturer::all();
        return view('asset', ['manufacturers' => $manufacturers]);
    }

    public function add(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
            'asset_id' => '',
            'asset_category_id' => 'required',
            'manufacturer_id' => 'required',
            'department_id' => 'required',
        ]);
        $assets =  new Asset;
        $assets  ->asset_id  = $request->input('asset_id');
        $assets  ->asset_category_id = $request->input('asset_category_id');
        $assets  ->manufacturer_id = $request->input('manufacturer_id');
        $assets  ->department_id = $request->input('department_id');
        $assets  ->save();
        return redirect('/viewAsset') ->with('info', 'New Asset Saved Successfully!');
    }

    public function update($id){
        $assets = Asset::find($id);
        return view('updateAsset', ['assets' => $assets]);

    }

    public function edit(Request $request, $id){

        $this->validate($request, [
            'asset_id' => '',
            'asset_category_id' => 'required',
            'manufacturer_id'=> 'required',
            'department_id' => 'required'
        ]);
        $data = array(
            'asset_category_id' => $request ->input('asset_category_id'),
            'manufacturer_id' => $request ->input('manufacturer_id'),
            'department_id' => $request ->input('department_id')
        );
        Asset::where('asset_id', $id)->update($data);    
        return redirect('/viewAsset') ->with('info', 'Asset Updated Successfully!');
    }

    public function delete($id){
        Asset::where('asset_id', $id)
            ->delete();
        return redirect('/viewAsset') ->with('info', 'Asset Deleted Successfully!');
    }
}
```

**Asset.php**

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Asset_category;

class Asset extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'asset_id';

    public function category(){

        return $this->belongsTo('Asset_category');
        //$this->belongsTo('Asset_category');
        //Asset_category::where('asset_category_id', $this->asset_category_id)->first()->category;
    }

}
```

**Asset_category.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Asset;

class Asset_category extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'asset_category_id';

    public function asset() {
        return $this->hasMany('Asset', 'asset_category_id');
    }
}
```

**viewAsset.php**

```
 @foreach($assets->all() as $asset)
 <tr>
    <td>{{ $asset->asset_id}}</td>
    <td>{{ $asset->category->category}}</td>
```

when i run the project i get a `FatalErrorExeception` which says

```
Class 'Asset_category' not found in HasRelationships.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You must end `@foreach` with `@endforeach`
2. You must declare `protected $table = 'table_name';` in model because in default laravel generate table name to plural form of model's class name
3. Try to return this:

   `return $this->belongsTo('Asset_category');`

   `return $this->hasMany('Asset', 'asset_category_id');`

to this:

`return $this->belongsTo(Asset_category::class);`

`return $this->hasMany(Asset::class, 'asset_category_id');`

Comment: i'm now getting Trying to get property of non-object ErrorException.@Nyicip

Comment: in which line? @Nii

Comment: The error is located in storage/framework/views/0bf0f93...php on line 55. I think the file which contains the error is automatically created by laravel when the application is executed.@Nyicip

Comment: what command in storage/framework/views/0bf0f93...php on line 55? You can check the file in `storage/framework/views` folder @Nii

Comment: It was returning an array and all i needed to do was to array access ([]) instead of an object access (->). So i got it working by changing in my blade {{ $asset->category->category}} to {{ $asset->category['category']}}. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have Asset_category in a namespace.  Try changing this:

```
return $this->belongsTo('Asset_category');
```

to this:

```
return $this->belongsTo(Asset_category::class);
```

Comment: i'm now getting|: Trying to get property of non-object ErrorException.@Jeff